# Are there any Intellisense-like autocomplete jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, intellisense

I am building a page that will require some sort of Intellisense/Autocomplete, is there any jQuery/Javascript plugins that you know of?

We are currently using a control similar to a normal autocomplete, where suggestions appear below the text area after writting a period (we then get the current token and do reflexion to get available methods), but I hoped there was something a little more polished on the frontend that we could use, something like the intellisense in [CodeRun](http://www.coderun.com/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: jQuery UI has an autocomplete widget, not sure if its like intellisense though. http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @Francisco Did you finally find anything good?